# Cause of "entry point could not be located" in unrelated DLL?

Tags: c, qt, visual-studio-2008, glib, matlab-deployment

Before you dismiss this question as a repeat, this question is different than the many other similar questions on SO because the **function** in the error message is **completely unrelated** to the **DLL**.

#### The app and version info

I've got a 32-bit app in Visual Studio 2008 RTM which uses a MATLAB Compiler 4.17 (R2012a) generated DLL, Glib (2.32.4, binaries from GStreamer SDK 2012.9 32-bit), and Qt (4.8.3-vs2008), all running on Windows 7 x64 SP1.

#### The problem

The **debug build runs fine**, but in release I get the infamous `The procedure entry point libXXXInitialize could not be located in the dynamic link library libglib-2.0-0.dll.` The bizarre thing is that this libXXXInitialize function (which does exist in the MATLAB-based DLL) is **totally unrelated** to libglib-2.0-0.dll.

#### My research

I checked the obvious, ensuring that all libraries were compiled with VS2008 (except for GStreamer/GLib which is compiled with mingw, but since it's straight C there shouldn't be any issues), and checking for any other versions of the DLLs in the path. It seems like it must be some sort of linker problem.

#### Update 1

In Dependency Walker x86, it shows this `libXXXInitialize` as an unresolved (parent) import from not only libglib-2.0-0.dll, but all the other GLib/GStreamer DLLs as well, however the function is correctly resolved in the DLL where it should be found, libXXX.dll.

#### Update 2

I removed the call to `libXXXInitialize` and called `mclInitializeApplication` from the MATLAB Compiler Runtime, and now that function is failing to be resolved from the glib DLL.

**However I found a solution** (at least temporary), changing the linker options from [`/OPT:REF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to `/OPT:NOREF` fixed the problem (so the linker "*keeps functions and/or data that are never referenced*). The bizarre thing is, I certainly use the `mclInitializeApplication` function explicitly, and if I turn on `/VERBOSE:REF`, it doesn't show it being removed.

#### Update 3

Finally found mention of this somewhere else, on the [bugtracker for binutils](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12633). I found this in [a MSVC2010 property sheet](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer-sdk/cerbero/tree/data/vs/msvc/common.props#n15) as part of the GStreamer SDK. Suggested workaround is what I'm already doing, disabling OptimizeReferences.

If anyone can tell me why this is happening, I'll mark it as the answer.